# Replace words in TextView with a smooth scale transition

Tags: android

Visit this website.

https://zapier.com/

See this portion of the website.

I wan that same in my android application that text changes after some time

[image]

For this i use count down timer to introduce delay between the text view changes. but it doesnt work.

Comment: If you post some code it would make your question clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:please be more specific in asking questions.**

Also have you tried anything yet..

It can simply be achieved by a **TimerTask** repeating in **desired interval**,, In which the **textView .setText(new value)**.
If you desire exact view as shown than the TextView width and height would be wrap content with text color white and background color black.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to subclass from TextView adding a timer and `text1` `text2` attributes, and calling `setText(text1)` or `setText(text2)` on timer ticks.

Comment: But what about the animation?

Comment: I didn't notice animation at first, my fault. Anyway adding it looks straightforward, no? I understand the question was: nothing changes for some reason.

Comment: Sure, the question is very confused :) I was just elaborating on the provided sample, and I don't think you can achieve the same effect with standard Android classes

Comment: Can't it be made as an alpha + scale animations?

Comment: It won't be a good approximation. The tricky part of that effect is the animation is applied only to certain words. Note how smoothly the "&" slides right and left

Comment: Ah, I see now. Indeed, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, I'm a co-founder of Zapier and we are not associated with this question nor do we condone adding vague questions to Stack Overflow. ;-)

If you can clarify what you are interested in (the animations? the timer? the css?) I'd be happy to talk about what we're doing. Not really sure what the reference to Android means.